# Opencart SEO Breaks Catogry Direct

Tags: php, seo, url-rewriting, opencart

Every time I enable SEO Rewrite, it brands one of my categories and links them to the incorrect page.

The hta file im currently using.

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess. 

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it    does    run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To explain further. When i disable SEO i can access my cables by category eg: Philips>Hdmi etc Then if I enable Seo, when trying to access Philips>hdmi I get the all the hdmi cables I sell on one page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're using the same SEO keyword (hdmi) for multiple categories. This isn't allowed as standard. You can check out [this mod](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6210) which allows you to have the same keyword for multiple categories (ie philips > hdmi, samsung > hdmi)